# Emacs crashes when I open a specific header file

Tags: emacs, sdl

I was digging through the header files for SDL  in Linux when I tried to open the file from the SDL library called "SDL_opengl.h" in Emacs.  For some reason, it always causes it to crash.  It opens just fine in Vim and in gedit.

Has anyone else had an issue with Emacs just plain refusing to open a particular file?  What sort of things should I look for to find what is causing the problem?  Mind you, I was able to open every other "SDL_*.h" file in that directory; just that one gives me trouble.

Much appreciated in advance!

Comment: A backtrace would be really useful.

start emacs with gdb and open it again.

gdb emacs
> r

Comment: Does it report something when it crashes? What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

I would be interested to see the exact error message, and stack trace if possible.

I suspect file encoding, special characters, file size, cc-mode parsing, or something like that to be the culprit.  (emacs 22 and libsdl1.2 on ubuntu 9 with utf-8 screen works fine for me)

Answer (score 1):

Converting my comment into an answer b/c the comments get cut off.

Try loading the file with

```
M-x find-file-literally
```

Since this (appears to) resolve the issue for giogadi, I think that points to perhaps the colorization of the buffer.  cc-mode does its own colorization...

Comment: 2022 and this helped with a PHP file that kept killing emacs.  Haven't bothered to look further, this is good enough.  Thank you! z

Answer (score 0):

Oh goodness, I'm a dunce.

So I apparently underestimated both the size of the file AND the speed of Emacs in opening said large files.

I decided to sit and wait to see if it dies completely on its own (as opposed to me xkill-ing it), and after a whole minute, the file is loaded.

So that solves one problem - the file is being loaded.  However, why would Emacs take so long to do it?  I have no strange settings enabled that should cause it to lag more than usual.

Comment: Is the loading speed the same if you start emacs with '-q' option? And, with '-q -no-site-file'?

Comment: What's the size of the file?  You might want to open large files with M-x find-file-literally    which forces fundamental mode.

Comment: Yeah, I tried running emacs with -q and --no-site-file and it's still hanging for about a minute before the file opens.  It's not even that big of a file - only 400KB at most.

Comment: What extension does it have (or, more importantly, what mode did it end up in)?  Did you try the find-file-literally?

Comment: I just opened that file. Including loading cc-mode it took about 1.5 seconds.

Comment: Interestingly, I just installed the snapshot of Emacs23 today and give it a try there and it works wonderfully.

As for Emacs22:  Trey's suggestion of using find-file-literally worked.  So, the problem lies somewhere in Emacs converting the format/character code.  But conversion shouldn't be that slow, should it?

Also, the mode it ends up in shouldn't be problem, since I've tried opening the file in fundamental mode.

Comment: Don't you know what "EMACS" stands for? "EMACS: EMACS Makes A Computer Slow" B-) (from the ...emacs/lib/humor folder...)

Answer (score 0):

have you hilit-mode on?
with hilit-auto-highlight-maxout and a great value?

I have had the same problem with header-files, so reduce that value.

maybe it is hs-mode (hideshow-mode)?